# Trouble indexing stock status

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I'm new to Magento, and just did a fresh install of 1.9.0.1. After the installation I'm able to re-index every item in indexadministration except stock status. For some reason it can't do it.

I've tried to delete all files in var/Locks which doesn't help. Secondly I've tried to create a PHP script that would do the trick. The PHP-script returns the following error:

```
'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'[my_db].cataloginventory_stock_status_idx' doesn't exist' 
(I've edited out my domain..)
```

I checked for the index in PHPmyadmin, and it seems that it doesn't exists. If someone could tell me which they have on the table, I might be able to re-create them manually.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

hi create installer file and on installer file add this code

**Step1:**
First of all create module control file Module name as  Amit_Custommodule.xml at app/etc/modules/. - See more at: http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/#sthash.filopkZM.dpuf

Amit_Custommodule.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    <depends>
    <Mage_CatalogInventory />
    </depends>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`Step2:`Create `config.xml aty app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/etc/` 
code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amit_Custommodule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Custommodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <custommodule_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amit_Custommodule</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_setup>
            <custommoule_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </custommoule_read>
            <custommodule_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </custommodule_write>
        </resources>
     </global>
</config>
```

**Step3:**`install-1.0.0.php`  path `app/code/community/Amit/Custommodule/sql/custommodule_setup/` and code

```
   <?php
    $installer=$this;
    $installer->startSetup();

        /**
         * Create table 'cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx'
         */
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx'))
            ->addColumn('product_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
                'unsigned'  => true,
                'nullable'  => false,
                'primary'   => true,
                ), 'Product Id')
            ->addColumn('website_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
                'unsigned'  => true,
                'nullable'  => false,
                'primary'   => true,
                ), 'Website Id')
            ->addColumn('stock_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
                'unsigned'  => true,
                'nullable'  => false,
                'primary'   => true,
                ), 'Stock Id')
            ->addColumn('qty', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '12,4', array(
                'nullable'  => false,
                'default'   => '0.0000',
                ), 'Qty')
            ->addColumn('stock_status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
                'unsigned'  => true,
                'nullable'  => false,
                ), 'Stock Status')
            ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx', array('stock_id')),
                array('stock_id')
            )
            ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx', array('website_id')),
                array('website_id')
            )
            ->setComment('Cataloginventory Stock Status Indexer Idx');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
    $installer->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx'),
    $installer->getIdxName('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx', array('stock_id')),
    array('stock_id')
);

$installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
    $installer->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx'),
    $installer->getIdxName('cataloginventory/stock_status_indexer_idx', array('website_id')),
    array('website_id')
);
$installer->endSetup()
```

;